# Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've installed Android studio 3.0.1 then tried to build very first app by choosing an empty activity, but I've got this message:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

and the error message like this:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom
> > Already seen doctype.

[image]

[image]

The first part of log message is like this:

> 2018-01-03 11:11:12,671 [d thread 8]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Already seen doctype.
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
> 2018-01-03 11:11:12,671 [d thread 8]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Already seen doctype.

I've tried some suggested solutions like changing gradle version, update Kotlin plugin(!) and so, but they didn't work.

Any solution?

Comment: Try this and build project . In Android Studio, Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle . Uncheck Offline work

Comment: Have you had `google()` as repository in your main `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Learner I've try that before. It is uncheck by default.

Comment: @Eselfar Yes I had it and the problem still stands.

Comment: What are you gradle, gradle build tools and buildToolsVersion versions?

Comment: @Eselfar Gradle version is 4.1

Comment: Hope this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220536/3974530

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem caused by my connection. I needed to set proxy to download some components.

Comment: Can you be more specific... what components where missing? I continue to have this trouble even after trying the other solutions.

Comment: @mjash, I too. Help me

Comment: For me, It was just a problem for downloading some components and the reason was the issue caused by google itself. So I've just changed my VPN connection and problem solved.
But recently I realized that this problem is more common and others have it with different reasons.

Comment: yep, only VPN helped me to download a necessary library correctly ("inapp-sdk")

Answer (score 12):

This problem occurs when the **Build Tools Version** is not set for the project.
You just set the build tools version by following this process...

By opening your project structure [[File->Project Structure]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Mwf.png) and selecting the **Build Tools Version** from app's property tab in Modules section.

This will add build tools version to your [gradle file (Module:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXLEi.png) and re-sync the project.

Comment: I set the Build Tools Version, but the problem is still stand.

Comment: What if there is no "app's property" tab in Module section? I only have a "Dependencies" tab.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all suggestions, only one works for me:

- open 'Gradle' tab on ***right*** vertical panel
- right click on project name
- 'Refresh Gradle Dependencies' and wait background downloading
- right click on project name again
- 'Reload Gradle Project' and wait refreshing

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was one of the external libraries required SDK 28 but android studio didnt have it so it did not work. I installed SDK 28 and the problem was fixed. I saw the problem in the log file it generated

Answer (score 2):

The error happens under fluctuating network. So at first make sure your connection is stable. Plus, if you are using any VPN check your `gradle.properties` is configured correctly.

The correct form of VPN connection on `gradle.properties` is as follows,

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

My host connection is `127.0.0.1`, and its port is `8080` for both `http` and `https`.

Just one more thing, make sure adding `https` (It is mandatory).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i was upgrading to android studio 3.1.2 and the problem i was using the previous JDK which i installed before 5 years back.

**The steps:-**

```
Go to File -> Project Structures -> SDK Location -> JDK Location -> check the 
Option Use embedded JDK (recommended).
```

Comment: Thanks you, this is amazing

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck with the same issue for quite few minutes till I figured out the solution:

So you have to visit [Gradle Releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) and
there scroll down a little bit and you will find the plugin version and required gradle version. Make sure you use the latest version of both or the ones which are compatible with each other.

For today I am using :

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version - 7.0.2

Gradle Version - 7.2
```

You can update it by navigating to:

`> File -> Project Structure -> Project`

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly My Project showing this Error(Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly). Then i Try to various solutions but not solved.
Then i close the android studio, and open the project location and delete the .idea and .iml file, After deleting this file open the project again on Android studio, after that the project working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I did download gradle version and used it as a local distribution.
Settings/Build,../Gradle/Use local distribution.
Else you will have to reinstall all the software.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is kinda of very simple. 
It's because the "compileSdkVersion" that you are using
in your build.gradle (Module:app) is higher than the SDK installed in your Android studio.
Now, what to do?
Just go on SDK Manager and download an Api Level higher or equal to your "compileSdkVersion" and you're done

Answer (score 0):

Look at the manifest, something may have to go wrong there. In my case I had this label
`<uses-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "7" android: targetSdkVersion = "15" />`, which was from an example.
Then the error is displayed, and the correspondent is now updated `<uses-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "15" android: targetSdkVersion = "27" />`

Answer (score 0):

As @oyeraghib said,
[Visit this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) to check the compatibility of your Android Gradle Plugin in comparison with Gradle itself. I was using an older version of both and updated to version 7 in both.

> File -> Project Structure -> Project

It may take a while. Wait for it to load.

Answer (score 0):

change the grade version to the latest one in gradle-wrapper

Answer (score -2):

Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Go to gradle scripts -> build gradle(app) -> made following changes:

[image]

Finally it works.

Comment: Please add a description of what your image/screenshot is about. You should also read about [how to write a good answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).