# gradle project sync failed error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I start a new project on Android Studio I get the following error:"Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g editing, debugging) will not work properly" how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096905/android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show debug info?
1. First try Invalidate cache and restart