# How to solve Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When i compile the Project and Run on the device than it's working fine  and i checked the app in real device by USB Cable and it's running perfect but when i try to generate the release apk or try to generate the debug apk than it show The Error that gradle sync faild can not generate the apk  and shows the warning/Error as

> Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

Comment: Do you want apk file immediatly, just create an apk file from already installed application. There are lots of application available for it.

Comment: you can find solution for it by browsing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096905/android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g . Most probably it caused due to proxy issue

Comment: #Lucefer can you please help me to set proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
go to Android Studio > Preferences > Gradle
then pass the proxy details as VM options.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

I added this from using this [AndroidStudio gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443208/androidstudio-gradle-proxy) solution

Answer (score -1):

If you want the apk immediately, then go to the project directory and run the following command in your terminal.

`find . -name '*.apk'`

you should be able to get your apk file path in your directory. That would be a debug apk which got created when you compiled your project and ran on the device. You can share that.

Comment: in android studio 3.+ this type of apk  dont install in devices for this one need to nuild debug/release apk