# Gradle build sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. Editing Debugging) will not work properly

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[Error screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okBiJ.png)

`plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.helloworld"
    minSdk 16
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

}`

The Above code is my build. Gradle

The Version of Android Studio --> Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2 for Windows 64-bit
I am Facing this Gradle build error since morning I had tried all the things Including once from Previous Stack Overflow Users who said still I am stuck Please Help every Advice will we consider as a blessing please Help

I had tried everything from the following posts but sadly Nothing works:

[Android Studio 3.0.1 Error: Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096905/android-studio-3-0-1-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionality-e-g)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8YXxZXlcMY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_vVIi_AOew

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h90Y_KMk1Z4

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Comment: The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip' does not exist.

Comment: You should connect to the internet and open your project again. It will download that distribution and save it locally.

Comment: I am already connected to internet From the starting

Comment: Can you check if you have that version in your home directory `~/.gradle/`

Comment: can you please provide the steps to check if I have that version in my home directory ~/.gradle/

Comment: Just open the terminal and enter `cd ~/.gradle/`. And then enter `ls -a` if on linux or `dir` if on windows cmd. Check if there is a folder named '7.2'. If on windows change the slashes in path name to backward slashes ( \ ), otherwise it will give error

Comment: In windows powerShell Right !!!!

Comment: Yes you can also use that. Open it and enter `cd ~\.gradle\ ` and then `ls` or `dir` (both works in powershell). Check for `7.2` folder

Comment: You should also look at `~\.gradle\wrapper\dists\ ` for `gradle-7.2.bin` folder, if you don't find in the home directory.

Comment: In ~\.gradle\ I dont find any  folder related to 7.2 so something but I found Something --> 852 gradle.properties

Comment: in ~\.gradle\wrapper\dists\ I found only gradle-7.2-bin Now what to do

Comment: It means that gradle-7.2 exists. See if there are other errors. And if possible, please provide the full error log (screenshot would be better).

Comment: `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\DEV\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar
C:\Users\DEV\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar
`

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Provided the error screenshot in the question part You can refer that there

Comment: What I suspect is, it is not problem with the gradle binary. It could not download some files. Did you try to create a new project and build that? Does it show the same error? Make sure you don't disconnect the network while creating a new project.

Comment: The error screen is the same no matter what so ever project I create or open

Comment: It looks like you will have to do more. Try [building the app from command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline), `cd` to the project root folder and run `gradlew assembleDebug`. Then show me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Project

Now make Android Gradle Plugin Version as 7.1.2

Gradle Version as 7.2

Update any other dependencies you are using also do Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: It is already that by default ..........

Comment: can you show your build.gradle once

Comment: plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.helloworld"
        minSdk 16
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

Comment: Also provided the build.gradle in the Question part You can refer that